# ng-init is not calling second time when track by $index used

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-track-by

html:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in Rows  track by $index" ng-init="initUserDecision(row,$index)" >
      <td>{{employeeName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="change"/>
```

controller:

```js
$scope.initUserDecision = function(row,index){
    $scope.employeeName=row["name"];
}
$scope.rows=[{id:1,name:'siva'},{id:2,name:'ram'}]
//changing $scope.rows in button click event and used $scope.$apply as well
angular.element(document).on("click", "#change", function () {
    $scope.rows=[{id:1,name:'ravi'},{id:2,name:'raj'}]
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

`ng-init` function calling first-time when tr initialized. if i click change button rows collection  gets changed  and it won't calling `ng-init` again. if i remove track by `$index` `ng-init` calling both  the times. when i use track by `$index` it was called only one time. why is it so ? Any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `track by $index`. Watch is kept on `data item` in `collection` by their `index` and not by `uid`.

1. `not track by`,

   In this case, `ngRepeat` create `new uid` for `data item` in collection whenever `collection is updated`. `ngRepeat` sees `new uids` and `re-renders` all elements.
2. `track by,($index)`

   In this case, `ngRepeat` uses `index as uid` for data item in collection. `ngRepeat` doesn't see any `new uids` and hence `no re-rendering` of elements (add or remove,if any, but `no rendering of others`). (As `watch` is kept on data, it will get `updated` but no-rendering)

Comment: OP's creating new objects on button click `$scope.rows=[{id:1,name:'ravi'},{id:2,name:'raj'}]`. where is $index kept?

Comment: ngRepeat's trackByIdFn uses index of item in collection and this index is given to transclusion scope.