# Modifying object in array that is being iterated over by ng-repeat from ng-init directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the position property on an object that is inside an array being used by ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-init="pos = $index + 1; item.position = pos">

<span>{{pos}}</span>

</div>
```

Initially it sets the property fine, however, anytime the HTML is recompiled after a model (I add/remove/move elements in the array) change the `pos` variable is set properly and correct position is displayed. However it will not update item.position !

Comment: How do you know it is not updating the `item.position`?

Comment: @Phil Well, I check the collection when debugging and also have UI elements that display {{item.position}} value

Comment: Reproduced the problem here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/Xk6fqGWFWAuaqHXvWdKs?p=preview. Seems to do with the reference to `item` in the `ng-init` as it's only ever updating the property in the last one

Comment: Do you need track by ? Try this `ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="pos = $index + 1;"`

Comment: Similar, question here (why?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976896/ng-init-is-not-calling-second-time-when-track-by-index-used/39977576#39977576

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of properties really doesn't belong in your template. You should ideally be assigning the `position` property in your controller. You could use something like this in your controller

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item, idx) {
        item.position = idx + 1;
    });
})
```

however I'd really question the need to do so. The item's position in the array provides all the information you need.

Demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/H5JbsABEdceSXENFFBBO?p=preview

Comment: Will probably end up using $watchCollection or a simple for loop, since only time objects change index is triggered by a single ui control as $watchCollection is quite expensive. I could probably get away with using no position property at all and just assign it when iterating over the array on server-side, however if I chose to only post back modified objects this would not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting hack:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  {{item.position=$index+1}}
    <span>{{item.position}}</span>
</li>
```

Wouldn't suggest it in production though

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sqy9grIdjMDQrBPsXUiC?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Your `<span>{{pos}}</span>` is redundant (and not displaying anything)

Comment: @Phil but using your random index insertion demo using the `=` in interpolation does update position correctly. Ugly but interesting

Comment: Not really surprising. The result of an assignment operation is typically the value assigned

Comment: right...that's why I threw it out there. Have never really used interpolation as a setter

Comment: Yes, this works. I could have sworn I tried this with no luck previously. Why would you say it's a hack though, evaluating expressions and assigning in double curly braces is supported it seems, so maybe not a hack ?

Comment: Maybe it's not such a hack. Easier to test in controller though rather than have view doing property changes on model